# Jni native C ++ didn't faster than java in android

Tags: java, android, c++

I have a code to process big float array in java but it is too slow. So I try to use Jni native C++ to improve performance and processing speed, but unfortunately, it still too slow. Even slower than java version. Here is my part of code for you to tell me how to improve it.

in android java:

```
private float[] nonMaxSuppression_java( float[] map,int w1,int w2,int w3, int window) {
    int size  = w1*w2*w3;
    float[] original = new float[w1*w2*w3];
    for(int d =0; d<w3;d++) {
        for (int i = 0; i < w1; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j <w2; j++) {
                float max = -99;
                float current = map[d+w3*(j+w2*i)];
                for (int row_offset = 0; row_offset < window; row_offset++) {
                    for (int col_offset = 0; col_offset < window; col_offset++) {
                        int row_index = i + row_offset - window / 2;
                        int col_index = j + col_offset - window / 2;
                        if (row_index < w1 && col_index < w2 && row_index >= 0 && col_index >= 0) {
                            float a = map[d+w3*(col_index+w2*row_index)];
                            if(map[d+w3*(col_index+w2*row_index)] > max) {
                                max = map[d+w3*(col_index+w2*row_index)];
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                if (current != max) {
                    original[d + w3 * (j + w2 * i)] = 0;
                } else {
                    original[d + w3 * (j + w2 * i)] = map[d+w3*(j+w2*i)];
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return original;
}
```

in native C++:

```
extern "C"
JNIEXPORT jfloatArray JNICALL
Java_com_asus_poseestimator_JNIUtils_nonMaxSuppression(JNIEnv *env, jobject instance, jfloatArray map_,jint w1,jint w2,jint w3, jint window) {
jfloat *map = env->GetFloatArrayElements(map_, 0);
int size  = w1*w2*w3
;
jfloatArray result = env->NewFloatArray(size);
float *original = new float[w1*w2*w3];
for(int d =0; d<w3;d++) {
    for (int i = 0; i < w1; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j <w2; j++) {
            float max = -99;
            float current = MAP(i,j,d);
            for (int row_offset = 0; row_offset < window; row_offset++) {
                for (int col_offset = 0; col_offset < window; col_offset++) {
                    int row_index = i + row_offset - window / 2;
                    int col_index = j + col_offset - window / 2;
                    if (row_index < w1 && col_index < w2 && row_index >= 0 && col_index >= 0) {
                        if(MAP(row_index,col_index,d) > max) {
                            max = MAP(row_index, col_index, d);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            if (current != max) {
                original[d + w3 * (j + w2 * i)] = 0;
            } else {
                original[d + w3 * (j + w2 * i)] = MAP(i, j, d);
            }
        }
    }
}
env->SetFloatArrayRegion(result, 0, size, original);
env->ReleaseFloatArrayElements(map_,map,0);
delete [] original;
return result;
```

}

I use Cmake to build JNI

```
   cmake {
        // for neon optimization:
        abiFilters "armeabi-v7a"
        cppFlags "-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE:STRING=Release -DHAVE_NEON -O3 -Wno-parentheses -mfpu=neon -mfloat-abi=softfp -march=armv7-a"
    }
```

Why java run this function faster than native C++?

Comment: "but unfortunately, my app is too slow" - if you have 5 nested for loops like that, then you should either be doing this in a background thread, or going back to the maths.  In any case though - you've not shown how you know it's slower.

Comment: I set System.currentTimeMillis();  in my code to get elapsed time. I just want to know why java version faster than native C++. Java cost about 500ms. native C++ cost about 1200ms.

Comment: Since you've not posted the code - the java might have to load the dll, look up the function, and ... do other things in java in the middle - who knows; alternatively, maybe you've got a debug build rather than optimised release build.  Or maybe the input data isn't identical - honestly - I don't think you've given us enough information

Comment: Along with what others have said, in java you access map[] directly. In C++ you have a mystery method MAP() which we can't see the code.

Answer (score 1):

The obvious way to improve both versions is by using sequential array access. Your loop variables are (outer to inner) `d,i,j` but your loop index is `[d + w3*j + w3*w2*i]`. To access the array sequentially, `[0]` should be followed by `[1]` which means that `d` should be the inner loop variable, not the outer.